# How to update primary key in another table where that key is foreign key at a same time using Entitty Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, foreign-keys

[image]

[image]

In my scenario, my user is claiming certain amount against bills. For each bill, there will be a single entry in the `details` table. Now, once user is done, he will doing the final submit. The total amount, will be going to the `items` table with necessary details. There will be only one entry in the **items** table against the multiple entries in **details** table. While entering data in `details` table, I am keeping the foreign key `EmpFlexiYearlyPayClaimItemId` as null, but at the final submit I need to update it.

How shall I approach?

Feel free to ask questions, if you have any doubt

I am using Entity Framework and C#.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you want to update: a primary key (not recommended) or a foreign key?

Comment: As per the given picture, I want to insert the 2nd table's primary key nto 1st table as foreign key

Comment: Column name already mentioned above

Comment: Updating a property/field using EF is nothing but setting its value and save changes. I don't see the problem.

Comment: @Gert, the issue is that, I want to insert data in the items table and update the data present in details table with the items table primary which is a foreign key in the details table

Comment: You should show your current code that doesn't do what you want. It's not clear what you want. In my view you just want to update `EmpFlexiYearlyPayClaimItemId` from `null` to some integer value that is an existing PK value in another table. How can that be a problem?